# Invoke Paypal app Android/iOS with receiver user

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I would like to know if its possible to invoke the Paypal application (if installed) from another app, going to the screen of transfers and giving the account to receive the money and the ammount for the user do the payment.

Comment: You can integrate in-app the [PayPal SDK Android](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK), the same can be done in [iOs SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK). However, consider to use it because some stores can reject your application if it contains another way to purchase/donate.

Comment: so... if I use another payment option in my app, the store can reject it? Example: if I let the user choose between Paypal and Google Checkout, will the store reject my app?

Comment: I think you can not (at least at Google Play, other markets maybe accept it). [In-app purchases:
Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.
Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment](http://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html). There are two exceptions visit the link.

Comment: My app fit in this exceptions but this link does not say anything about multiple payment options.